# loading csv file data into oracle database

Tags: java, sql-loader

I am trying to load a csv file in oracle database using sql loader through java program. I have successfully executed it by run command, but i want to load csv file data in database through a java program. My programs are:

1. loadCsv.csv:

   ```
   ID,firstName,LastName,Address
   1,aditya,kumar,gaya
   2,abhijeet,chanda,kol
   3,Rahul,Jordar,kol
   ```
2. trial.ctl:

   ```
   LOAD DATA
   INFILE loadCsv.csv
   BADFILE trial.bad
   DISCARDFILE trial.dsc
   APPEND 
   INTO TABLE load1
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY "”"
   (x,y,z,t)
   ```
3. SqlLoaderTest.java:

   ```
   public class SqlLoaderTest
   {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           try {
               String sqlldrCmd = "sqlldr control=E:\\load_data\\trial.ctl"+
                  "LOG=trial.log "+
                  "DATA=E:\\load_data\\loadCsv.csv USERID=vehere/adi"+
                  "BAD=E:\\load_data\\trial.bad";
               System.out.println("SQLLDR Started ....... ");
               Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
               Process proc = rt.exec(sqlldrCmd);
               System.out.println("SQLLDR Ended ........  ");
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

It is compiled and run successfully but not inserting any data in database. your suggestion is highly appreciated.Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my error. The right code is:

```
  public class SqlLoaderTest
  {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String sqlldrCmd = "sqlldr username/pwd, control=trial.ctl";

        System.out.println("SQLLDR Started ....... ");
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(sqlldrCmd);
        System.out.println("SQLLDR Ended ........  ");
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid, it does not run successfully, you just do not know what the error is.

Note that, if the `sqlldr` is executed, but fails do load the file into DB, you will not get any Java excaptions. Instead, the `Process` will [return a non-zero exitValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29), and there will probably be some output on the process' console.

What you need to do is to [take the `InputStream` of your `Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29), and log it somehow (for example, dump it into the console), so you can see what the `sqlldr` output is. Alternatively, redirect output of `sqlldr` to a file in your `sqlldrCmd` string.